# try catch на каждую строчку или общий

Tags: java

Предположим у нас есть код:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int A = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
int B = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
reader.close();
```

Получается так, что каждая из трех строчек снизу может вызвать IOException. Я должен завернуть их в один общий try catch или каждую в отдельности, как правильно?
P.S. достаточно ли вызвать close только на reader? Типа у нас есть и BufferedReader и InputStreamReader

Comment: Общий, если тип исключения один и тот же, и только на reader

Answer (score 1):

Для `IOException` используйте [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) c одним catch:

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
    int A = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int B = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    //что-то
}
```

`close` писать не нужно, т.к. в этой конструкции `reader` закрывается автоматически по завершении блока ([вместе с `InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close--)). Если по каким-то причинам нужно использовать обычный `try`, то `reader.close` нужно помещать в блок `finally`, с отделением инициализации `reader` и проверкой на null.

Не вижу смысла отдельно отлавливать `IOException` для каждой строки. Если сломается ввод﻿/﻿вывод, то это повлияет на исполнение всего блока.

Другое дело ошибки парсинга (`NumberFormatException`), которые может выбросить `parseInt`. Их обработка зависит от того как Вы хотите реагировать на неправильный ввод со стороны пользователя. Если в таком случае нужно вывести ошибку и выйти из программы, то достаточно одного `catch`. Если нужно перезапросить число, то понадобится и отдельный `try`и отдельный цикл и, скорее всего, отдельный метод для ввода.

Comment: Предположим, я почему-то не хочу использовать try с ресурсами, а делаю по старинке (JDK7) close в finally` BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String s = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader!= null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }`
Почему IDEA требует обернуть в try catch close? И почему подсказывает, что reader!= null always true? @default locale

Comment: @GrossmasteR Ну, во-первых, try с ресурсами появился в JDK 7 :). Во-вторых, создание `reader` нужно отделить от объявления переменной т.к. при создании может быть выброшено исключение. Ну и в-третьих: `close` теоретически может выбросить исключение, поэтому в Java его нужно тоже обернуть в try.

Comment: @GrossmasteR Пример работы по старинке можно посмотреть здесь: https://www.journaldev.com/592/java-try-with-resources#java-6-resource-management-example